# making borders on matches in feature matching open cv

Tags: python, opencv

im trying to create a project in which we provide the template image and a scene and then use feature matching of open cv python to detect if that object exist in that scene and make a rectangle or square around the matche found.......this the first step of the project after this im gonna integrate it.

```
`import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

#reading images
template = cv.imread("dimitrescu1.jpg")
template = cv.cvtColor(template, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
w,h = template.shape[::-1]
template = cv.resize(template, (int(w/2),int(h/2)))
image = cv.imread("dimitrescu2.jpg")
image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
w,h = image.shape[::-1]
image = cv.resize(image, (int(w/2),int(h/2)))

#initiate sift detector
orb = cv.ORB_create(nfeatures = 1500)

#creating keypoints and descriptors
kp1,des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(template,None)
kp2,des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(image,None)

#creating a brute force matcher and using knearest approach
bf = cv.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

#findind matches and setting threshold
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.8*n.distance:
        good.append([m])

#drawing matches
img3 = cv.drawMatchesKnn(template,kp1,image,kp2,good,None,flags = 2)

cv.imshow('hey',img3)
cv.waitKey(0)

print(len(good))

`
```

this is my code so far.i just cant figure out how to draw the borders around the matches.
any help will be appereciated.

Comment: you mean a bounding box?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki yes something like that ...which shows where the detected object is in the scene.

Comment: https://www.educba.com/opencv-bounding-box/

Comment: you cannot detect arbitrary objects using feature matching (it does not know about "objects"). broken plan. however, you can try to find the homography from the good matches, and project the original bb into the sxene